# Why does my SwiftUI page title change when a picker option is selected?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-picker

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    let settings: [Setting] = [
        Setting(name: "Aperture Increments", options: ["1/3", "1/2", "1"]),
        Setting(name: "Shutter Speed Increments", options: ["1/3", "1/2", "1"]),
        Setting(name: "ISO Increments", options: ["1/3", "1/2", "1"])
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(self.settings, id: \.name) { setting in
                    SettingDetailView(setting: setting)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}

struct SettingDetailView: View {
    let setting: Setting
    @State var selection: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text(setting.name)) {
            ForEach(self.setting.options, id: \.self) { option in
                Text(option).tag(option)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(setting.name), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, this problem is solved by wrapping the `Form` in a `Section` and defining the `navigationBarTitle` on it.

```
Form {
  Section {
    ...
  }.navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
}.navigationBarTitle("Settings")
```

I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834220/839733), although I've no idea why the title needs to be defined twice.

Comment: I have checked in your sample code with Form { Section {}} but it is not working for me.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya What is not working for you, can you be more specific? Are you still seeing the behavior in my original question?

Comment: Yes I can see the picker title

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya You're mistaken. I just checked again in a standalone project, and it works exactly like I said. See for yourself https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4fdjekqt4igli7/PickerDemo.zip?dl=1. I'm using Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Yes, Working Now :), There is one silly mistake thanks :)